# Finding the resistance of platinum wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, power

Im currently lost on solving this potentially simple electricty question and was wondering if anyone in this community could hint me or tell me which equations and why these equations would be necessary in order to solve these types of questions.

Im happy to read theoretical explanations regarding the equations in order to gain more insight on the uses and concepts of such.

> Q: Estimate the resistance of a platinum wire that is 100µm in diameter and 30mm long? What power would be dissipated in the wire if 5V were placed over it?

Thank you so much for taking the time to read this question and being able to demonstrate how this question can be solved.

Comment: why was the question -1'd?

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Comment: Thanks Kyle its noted. Although my question doesn't violate the guideline as I was looking for a conceptual understanding on which formulas are required and NOT asking for the solutions to the question. My intentions were never to seek solutions rather ask for help on concepts and related formulas that would help solve this question. I'm sorry if my question was not specifically detailed in general, I'll do my best next time.

Comment: That's the thing. A question like "Which formula is required?" is not conceptual. The conceptual question behind this would be, why the formula is the way it is and/or how to derive this formula from "physical principles".

Comment: Yes, I agree. As mentioned earlier it was never my intention to break guidelines. I respect keeping the quality of SE and ensure that in future my questions are more precise in the way it is asked. I would like to apologise to the physics community on SE  and hope you could forgive me.

Comment: I have edited the question to be more suited to the guidelines of Physics SE. Please note my apologies and hope the generous physicians could continue to help me with my curiosities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first part of your question, use the formula $$R = \rho \frac{l}{A}$$ where $R$ is resistance of wire, $l$ is length of wire, $A$ is area of cross-section of wire and $\rho$ is resistivity of material (platinum).

For second part of your question, use the formula $$P = \frac{V^2}{R}$$ where $P$ is the power delivered, $V$ is the potential difference and $R$ is resistance of wire.

So you need to convert your units to SI ($\mu$m and mm to m) and use the value of resistivity of platinum which you have not mentioned in your question.

Comment: Oh okay. Thankyou I understand it now.